# Function in C faster than in C++

Tags: c++, c, performance, clang

I want to write a small library, which has to do some calculations. The library should be written in C++ with a wrapper in C to allow external calls.

As an example, the C++ code would like this (just a very simple example)

```
complex<double> lorentz(double x, double A, double E0, double Br){
    return A * E0 * Br / (E0*E0 - x*x - I * Br * x);
}

// wrapper for the c-call
int call_fkt(double *energy, int N, double *parameter, int N_para, double *chi_real, double *chi_imag){
    for(int idx_ener = 0; idx_ener < N; idx_ener++){
        chi_real[idx_ener] = 0.0;
        chi_imag[idx_ener] = 0.0;
        complex<double> tmp;
        tmp = lorentz(energy[idx_ener], parameter[0], parameter[1], parameter[2]);
        chi_real[idx_ener] += real(tmp);
        chi_imag[idx_ener] += imag(tmp);
     }
}
```

A pure C version would look like:

```
double complex lorentz(double x, double A, double E0, double Br){
    return A * E0 * Br / (E0*E0 - x*x - I * Br * x);
}

// wrapper for the c-call
int call_fkt(double *energy, int N, double *parameter, int N_para, double *chi_real, double *chi_imag){
    for(int idx_ener = 0; idx_ener < N; idx_ener++){
        chi_real[idx_ener] = 0.0;
        chi_imag[idx_ener] = 0.0;
        double complex tmp;
        tmp = lorentz(energy[idx_ener], parameter[0], parameter[1], parameter[2]);
        chi_real[idx_ener] += creal(tmp);
        chi_imag[idx_ener] += cimag(tmp);
     }
}
```

which is about a factor 2 faster than the C++ version. Where does this difference come from? Are the math libraries in C faster than in C++?

Note, I know, that this example does not require C++ but I have a more complicated problem, which is much easier to solve in C++.

## Update

Here are the two versions I compiled. The C - code is

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

double complex lorentz(double x, double A, double E0, double Br){
    return A * E0 * Br / (E0*E0 - x*x - I * Br * x);
}

int c_call(double *energy, int N, double *parameter, int N_para, double *chi_real, double *chi_imag){
    for(int idx_ener = 0; idx_ener < N; idx_ener++){
        int start_index = 0;
        chi_real[idx_ener] = 0.0;
        chi_imag[idx_ener] = 0.0;
        double complex tmp;
        tmp = lorentz(energy[idx_ener], parameter[0], parameter[1], parameter[2]);
        // if (idx_ener == 1){
        //     printf("Hallo, idx ener = %i, start index =  %i\n", idx_ener, start_index);
        // }
        chi_real[idx_ener] += creal(tmp);
        chi_imag[idx_ener] += cimag(tmp);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

which is compiled by using

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -O3 -ffast-math -o pure_c.so pure_c.c
```

The C++ version is

```
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const complex<double> I(0.0,1.0);

complex<double> lorentz(double x, double A, double E0, double Br){
    return A * E0 * Br / (E0*E0 - x*x - I * Br * x);
}


extern "C" void c_call(double *energy, int N, double *parameter, int N_para, double *chi_real, double *chi_imag){
    for(int idx_ener = 0; idx_ener < N; idx_ener++){
        int start_index = 0;
        chi_real[idx_ener] = 0.0;
        chi_imag[idx_ener] = 0.0;
        complex<double> tmp;
        tmp = lorentz(energy[idx_ener], parameter[0], parameter[1], parameter[2]);
        // if (idx_ener == 1){
        //     printf("Hallo, idx ener = %i, start index =  %i\n", idx_ener, start_index);
        // }
        chi_real[idx_ener] += real(tmp);
        chi_imag[idx_ener] += imag(tmp);
    }
    return;
}
```

and is compiled by using

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -O3 -ffast-math -o mixed_c.so mixed_c.cpp
```

For measuring the execution time, I use a Python script. (The code should also be callable by means of another program. The measured time will be roughly the same.)

```
import numpy as np
# import ctypes
import time
from ctypes import CDLL, c_double, c_int, POINTER


N = 20088
N_time = 10000
ener = np.linspace(0.62, 6.2, N)
ener_c = (ener.astype(np.double)).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))

chi_real = (N * c_double)()
chi_imag = (N * c_double)()
p = np.array([2, 3, .01])

se_lib = CDLL("pure_c.so")
se_lib.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), c_int, POINTER(c_double), c_int, POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_double)]




times = np.zeros(N_time)
for idx in range(N_time):
    t1 = time.time()
    p_ctype = (p.astype(np.double)).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
    se_lib.c_call(ener_c, N, p_ctype, 3, chi_real, chi_imag)
    df  = 1 + np.array(chi_real) +  1j * np.array(chi_imag)  
    t2 = time.time()
    times[idx] = (t2 - t1)*1e3

print("time (pure): mean / median ", np.round(np.mean(times), 3) , " / ", np.round(np.median(times), 3), "s")

se_lib2 = CDLL("mixed_c.so")
se_lib2.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), c_int, POINTER(c_double), c_int, POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_double)]
for idx in range(N_time):
    t1 = time.time()
    p_ctype = (p.astype(np.double)).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
    se_lib2.c_call(ener_c, N, p_ctype, 3, chi_real, chi_imag)
    df  = 1 + np.array(chi_real) +  1j * np.array(chi_imag)  
    t2 = time.time()
    times[idx] = (t2 - t1)*1e3

print("time (mixed c): mean / median ", np.round(np.mean(times), 3) , " / ", np.round(np.median(times), 3), "s")
```

I already recognize that the fast-math flag speed up the C version a lot, whereas the enhancement in C++ is not that fast. Is there a way to achieve the same performance improvements?

Update 2:

- I use Apple clang version 14.0.3 in order to compile this code.
- I fixed the typo mentioned by @ComicSansMS

Update 3:

Looks like that this issue is caused by the compiler supplied by Apple as suggested by @n.m.couldbeanAI. Times are similar on a Ubuntu machine usig g++/gcc or clang.

Comment: What compiler and flags? Did you enable optimizations?

Comment: How do you measure "faster"? What are measurement results? What is the exact difference? What is the input you used for measurement?

Comment: without more details this is like asking "Why is the red horse faster than the green one?". Quesitons about benchmarking need to include the way you measured the time and how you build the code in addition to a [mcve]

Comment: Your C++ code still uses C-type for complex numbers. I think plan was to have: `return A * E0 * Br / std::complex<double>(E0*E0 - x*x, - Br * x);` and not use `I`.

Comment: Note: One legitimate speed-up C could have that (standard) C++ couldn't is the ability to declare all those `double*` parameters as `restrict`, enabling a small amount of optimization by removing the need for the code to assume that the modifications through `chi_real` and `chi_imag` might change the values found through `energy` or `parameter`. But you're not actually using that feature, so my psychic powers tell me you just compiled both without optimizations enabled, and `complex<double>` ended up running slower due to all the templating stuff that is usually inlined not being inlined.

Comment: Unrelated: Is there a reason why `chi` is not _one_ array/vector of complex numbers instead of two separate arrays (in both C and C++)?

Comment: In C++, you should initialize directly rather than declare and then assign. The C++ code initializes `tmp` to 0, which the C code doesn't.

Comment: Do the updated C and C++ functions really do the same thing? The C function returns a regular `double` while the C++ function returns a `std::complex<double>`. That doesn't look right.

Comment: Side note: your wrapper accepts parameter `N_para` but does not use it.  It instead just assumes that `parameter` provides access to at least three `double`s.

Comment: Try stock clang, gcc, and libstdc++. Apple clang is weird sometimes.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thanks for the information. I tried this using Ubuntu and the performance is here similar. (gcc and g++ 11.4)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I installed clang-15 by means of macports and still get the same discrepancy. I also changed the path for the library and lib during the compilation (i.e. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include) Should I consider something else?

Comment: Yes, **use gcc and/or libstdc++**. The problem seems to be with libc++ (not with the Apple compiler vs the stock compiler but with the clang standard library vs the gcc standard library).

Comment: Performance on my Linux machines is very similar between C and C++ using gcc (sometimes C is a bit faster and sometimes C++ is, depending on the compiler versions, but never 2x). Clang++ with libstdc++ is similar again, but clang++ with libc++ is 2x slower than everything else.

Comment: Note that `-ffast-math` (and `-Ofast`) are *dangerous* options to use. They break certain rules of the language to obtain fast code. You can get silently incorrect results in some cases when those options are used. Unless you know *very well* what you are doing and the exact effects those options can have and how they may impact your code, you should *not* use them.

Answer (score 3):

The implementations are not equivalent. Your C version of the `lorentz()` function returns a `double`, when it should be returning a `double complex`:

```c
double complex lorentz(double x, double A, double E0, double Br){
    return A * E0 * Br / (E0*E0 - x*x - I * Br * x);
}
```

With this change, I see no measurable performance difference on gcc 13.2.

Comment: This was a typo. Sorry. I still get not the same results: 60µs for the pure C version and about 180µs for the version using C++. (compiled using Apple clang version 14.0.3)

Comment: The speed is roughly the same if I not use the fast-math option

Comment: @Itzui Why do you post a question about gcc/g++ when you are compiling with AppleClang?

Comment: Sorry for this confusion. I 'm a beginner and wanted, as you did, mention the version of the compiler. When I asked gcc and g++ for the version I got the information that the command just call clang.

Answer (score 1):

clang cannot inline complex arithmetic operators from libc++. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j9xKadPzz).

Perhaps this is not so unexpected, given how *complex* the libc++ [implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/78d6a7767ed57b50122a161b91f59f19c9bd0d19/include/complex#L667) of `std::complex` operators is, compared to the libstdc++ [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/bd7257f08c9b18bdd66a59bff2e02801a8aaf340/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/complex#L308).

Comment: Thanks again, for the information. Looks like, that I have to use g++.